# How to swap keys and values of an association?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, associations

How do you swap the values and keys of an Association in a manner similar to taking the transpose of a two-dimensional matrix or nested list?
I am trying to solve the Wolfram Challenge [Capital Cities Near a Latitude](https://challenges.wolfram.com/challenge/capital-cities-near-a-latitude)
I created an association of data with the capital of each country as the key and the difference between a specific latitude (I chose 38° in this example, but any value can be used by replacing it with a function's parameter variable) as follows:

```
data = AssociationMap[Abs[QuantityMagnitude@#["Latitude"] - 38] &, 
  DeleteMissing@EntityValue["Country", "CapitalCity"]]
```

I then sort the data in ascending order:

```
Sort[data]
```

My next goal was to extract my goal of Athens as the answer:
[image]
Part does not work because it returns the value referring to the latitude difference, not the key referring to the capital city:

```
Sort[data][[1]]
```

[image]

The way I found was roundabout, prompting me to think if there is a
better way:

```
(Keys@Take[Sort[data], 1])[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: This may be a dangerous proposition if your keys and values are not all distinct among them. I suspect that there might be another solution to the problem you are trying to solve in this way: tell us more about the context in which this problem arose for you.

Comment: I explain what I am trying to do within the body of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose `AssociationThread[Values@assoc, Keys@assoc]`, but it's not invertible if the values are not distinct.

Also `Association@KeyValueMap[#2 -> #1 &, assoc]` with the same caveat.

Answer (score 1):

```
TakeSmallest[data, 1]
(* <|Entity["City", {"Athens", "Attiki", "Greece"}] -> 0.02|> *)
```