# How can I invert the association?

Tags: syntax, associations

Consider an association

```
assoc := Association[{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2} ]
```

How can I invert it, i.e., to obtain the following?

```
assocInvert:=Association[{1->"a",2->"b"}]
```

Comment: On inverting associations: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130089/reverse-lookup-getting-keys-from-values/130113#130113 -- e.g. ``GeneralUtilities`AssociationInvert[assoc]``. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258622/how-to-swap-keys-and-values-of-an-association

Comment: `AssociationThread[Values@assoc -> Keys@assoc]` for well defined cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Association[KeyValueMap[Reverse@*Rule, assoc]]
```

or

```
Association[Reverse /@ Normal[assoc]]
```

Comment: The implementation of ```GeneralUtilities`AssociationInvert``` is, perhaps more simply, `AssociationThread[Values[assoc], Keys[assoc]]`.

Comment: @MarcoB excellent! why did you not make that an answer?